# Assaultcube won't launch Ubuntu 20.04.1 kernel 5.8.0-40-generic

Tags: kernel, games

```
./ac_client(+0xe983e) [0x55dac9b8c83e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x46210) [0x7f302b46f210]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x3b5863) [0x7f3027e88863]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x123b00) [0x7f3027bf6b00]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2aed16) [0x7f3027d81d16]
./ac_client(+0x83a87) [0x55dac9b26a87]
./ac_client(+0x8b7e1) [0x55dac9b2e7e1]
./ac_client(+0x8c252) [0x55dac9b2f252]
./ac_client(main+0x10b5) [0x55dac9b13835]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f302b4500b3]
./ac_client(+0x1d64e) [0x55dac9ac064e]
AssaultCube error (11) ()
OpenAL Error (A004): invalid operation, line 359
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

This error is registered. The game crashes

Comment: Have you tried to reboot with previous kernel version? If not - reboot computer, press <Shift>, in GRUB go to advanced options, select previous kernel version, boot then retry launching AssaultCube.

Comment: I've rebooted with previous kernel (5.8.0-38) ,the game still crashes. The game used to run smoothly with kernel 5.4

Comment: ***There are known current regressions with the 5.8.0 kernel.  DO NOT use Kernel 5.8.0 if you are experiencing issues at this time, and use the 5.4.X kernel as is suggested in N0rbert's answer.***

Comment: I've tried it out myself .. we're working on the 1.3 release ATM .. a DEBUG build was able to run, a regular build crashes as posted above. I'll investigate some more!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following:

1. Reboot the system into GRUB and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then select *Advanced options for Ubuntu* line, and then choose line with oldest Linux 5.4 and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot system using it.
2. Login to the system, open terminal to execute commands below to get General Availability (GA) 5.4 kernel back:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 \
   linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 "linux-*5.8*"

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
   ```
3. Reboot to use latest GA Linux 5.4 kernel version.

---

Note: to revert the changes and to use 5.8 HWE kernel execute `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04` .

Answer (score 0):

The client does not appear to run properly in this environment; you *can* get it started by using the `--loadmap` argument on the command-line like so:

```
./assaultcube.sh -t -w1024 -h768 --loadmap=ac_mines
```

Other maps that work include **ac_douze** - good old makkE maps :-) - **ac_werk** for instance **reliably crashes** the client.
So - this isn't something you can use for online playing; the release is from 2013 and hence didn't have the newest drivers and library versions to bugfix against.

[The AssaultCube project](https://assault.cubers.net/) is currently *preparing for* **the release of version 1.3** the ALPHA2 of which is running smoothly on my system!